# can change string variable, but not innerHTML

Tags: replace, innerhtml

I need to remove some part of an innerHTML. I've been trying this for 3 hours now. It seems so simple.

This does work...

```
var foo = '<div id = "test" class = "hidden" style = "width: 350px"></div>';
alert(foo);
foo = foo.split('id = "test" class = "hidden" ').join('');
alert(foo);
```

And this doesn't...

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('kjbggk');

myElement.innerHTML = '<div id = "test" class = "hidden" style = "width: 350px"></div>';
alert(myElement.innerHTML);
myElement.innerHTML = myElement.innerHTML.split('id = "test" class = "hidden" ').join('');
alert(myElement.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982268/element-reference-breaks-on-modification-of-innerhtml-property-of-container) to go to a related StackOverflow question that may solve your issue.

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196240/setting-innerhtml-why-wont-it-update-the-dom) also seems related to your question.

Alternately, have you tried

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById('kjbggk');
alert(myElement.innerHTML);
var foo = '<div id = "test" class = "hidden" style = "width: 350px"></div>';
alert(foo);
foo = foo.split('id = "test" class = "hidden" ').join('');
alert(foo);
myElement.innerHTML = foo;
alert(myElement.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still able to change "test" into "", so the id actually can change. I'll read the links you gave me.

Comment: I could not solve it. Started studying the DOM model. I'm almost certain it will solve the problem (although it needs a lot of (simple) code to do so). http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp

Comment: Have you considered assigning the value of `innerHTML` to a variable like `foo` in your first example, manipulating `foo`, then assigning `foo` to `innerHTML`?  I updated my answer to reflect this suggestion.

Comment: yes, yes, tried, but doesn't work. But thank you for the suggestion. But the DOM model is going to do the trick. Start working on that today.